# API key not valid error when trying to get profile data

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to test Google login API. I want to retrieve some basic data after the client logs.

I created a Google API Console project and client ID  (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project)

Here is google official code (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#LoadinganAPIandMakingaRequest):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleClientLoad() {
        // Loads the client library and the auth2 library together for efficiency.
        // Loading the auth2 library is optional here since `gapi.client.init` function will load
        // it if not already loaded. Loading it upfront can save one network request.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      function initClient() {
        // Initialize the client with API key and People API, and initialize OAuth with an
        // OAuth 2.0 client ID and scopes (space delimited string) to request access.
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: '5v2RzP7-xyQGNjxrD5suoPL9',
            discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
            clientId: '298062822261-e5c09q8191mkho0o7n3n3obiq2eq2p3f.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'profile'
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
      }

      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        // When signin status changes, this function is called.
        // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
        if (isSignedIn) {
          makeApiCall();
        }
      }

      function handleSignInClick(event) {
        // Ideally the button should only show up after gapi.client.init finishes, so that this
        // handler won't be called before OAuth is initialized.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      function handleSignOutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      function makeApiCall() {
        // Make an API call to the People API, and print the user's given name.
        gapi.client.people.people.get({
          resourceName: 'people/me'
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log('Hello, ' + response.result.names[0].givenName);
        }, function(reason) {
          console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
            onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
            onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <button id="signin-button" onclick="handleSignInClick()">Sign In</button>
    <button id="signout-button" onclick="handleSignOutClick()">Sign Out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ClientId and apikey are from my google api.

I receive error 400

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong whit my api key. I followed all the steps from google documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using the client secret as API key. Isn't it?

To obtain an API key you must create it.

Under credentials (dev console) click on create credential, and then 'API Key'

Comment: I modified whit the new api key but i have the same error.

Comment: Error 400..but i don't know why I can't open the content of the error.

Comment: Maybe another error.debug and analyse the 'response' variable

Comment: I've been tried your code and changed the clientID and API key with mine and works fine (it shows 'Hello '+ my profile name).